# Adding Users By Phone Number To Custom Audiences

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

As stated in documentation, it is possible to add users to Facebook Custom Audiences using emails, phone numbers, facebook id or even app user id. But only email option is documented on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/custom-audience-targeting/

We can use "email_hash" key while adding users by emails. What are the keys to use while adding users by phone number or facebook ids?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I posted random names and in response i found correct key names for other options:

> (#100) Users must use one of id, partner_token, email_hash, phone_hash, custom_audience_third_party_id.